# Blob Storage Azure and javascript, how to list all snapshots for a specific blob

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-node-sdk

Beginning a nodejs project, I need to retrieve the latest snapshot (and its metadata) for a specific blob. I'm using the Azure Blob storage client library v12 for JavaScript.

I'm not sure but I only found a method linked to the ContainerClient permitting to list all the blobs and snapshot within the container. Imo it's not for me very efficient in term of performance.

Is there a way to directly get the latest snapshot of a known blob or at least get all the snapshots ?

```
//construct of the blob storage connection
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
    `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/`,
    sharedKeyCredential
);
//target application container
let containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(app);
blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(filename); //ok
//blobSnapshots = containerClient.getSnapshots(filename); // nok
```

The method in the last commented line for sure doesnt exist but is there an equivalent method ?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to directly get the latest snapshot of a known blob

Unfortunately no. You will need to list all snapshots of a blob and sort them reverse chronologically based on snapshot date/time and pick the 1st blob. That would be the latest snapshot.

> or at least get all the snapshots ?

You will need to call [`listBlobsFlat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/containerclient?view=azure-node-latest#listblobsflat-containerlistblobsoptions-) method with the following [`options`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/containerlistblobsoptions?view=azure-node-latest):

- [`prefix`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/containerlistblobsoptions?view=azure-node-latest#prefix): This should be the name of the blob.
- [`includeSnapshots`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/containerlistblobsoptions?view=azure-node-latest#includesnapshots): Value of this parameter should be true.

Comment: great it should do the job. And how do I get the snapshot url ?

Comment: I’ve not tried it but you should get the snapshot URL in the blob’s URL. If not, then just add “?snapshot=<snapshot date/time>” to the blob URL.